# Set Cursor Position in Input Relative to Div click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image: Example text]

As you can see above the standard action of input is to set focus to where the cursor was when typing or editing.

Using the example above I'm trying to make it so that when you `click` on div above it sets the `cursor` position relative to the Div click.

Native JavaScript with React.

My current code is simply `onClick` set `focus` to `input`.

Goal:
The code is reflected in the div above. I will then wrap `spans` around certain keywords to give affect like so:

[image: Numi Calculater]

The input will be then hidden and the div will mimic and look like a text box.

Comment: use the co-ordinates of the mouse click event to calculate the correct position - it's not easy though with a variable width font of course

Comment: @JaromandaX Won't work because of the input not text wrapping. The position will be invalid if the mouse click in div is on the second line